# Encountered two children with the same key, `function v4(options, buf, offset)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

```
import {v4 as uuidv4} from "uuid"

<div ref={scrollRef} key={uuidv4}>
     <div className={`message ${message.fromSelf ? "sended" : "recieved"}`}>
          <div className="content">
               <p>{message.message}</p>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

why am i getting two children fo same key error in console?
can someone please explain and also provide a solution for this?

i cant seem to find a solution for this warning.

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially passing `uuidv4` function as the key, so it will be the same for all the elements. Please call the function as below

```
<div ref={scrollRef} key={uuidv4()}> <div className={message ${message.fromSelf ? "sended" : "recieved"}`}>
```

Notice the invocation of the `uuidv4()`